# creating a list in list python

Tags: list, for-loop, indexing, range

i have to write a function that takes as an input  a list and if to Consecutive numbers have the same sighn then they both go to a same list in lists if not a new list in list is opened for example:

```
 [2,5,-3,-1,-1,3,-2,-2]->[[2,5]],[-3,-1,-1],[3],[-2,-2]]
```

this  is my code :

```
 def num_8(lst):
    my_lst=[[lst[0]]]
    j=0
    for i in range(1,len(lst)):
        if (lst[i]> 0 and lst[i-1]>0) or (lst[i]<0 and lst[i-1]<0):
            my_lst[j].append(lst[i])
            print(my_lst)
        else:
            j=j+1
            my_lst[j].append([lst[i]])
    return my_lst
print(num_8([2,5,-3,-1,-1,3,-2,-2]))
```

but  i keep on getting

```
  my_lst[j].append([lst[i]])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

and i dont know were i get out of range :( thanks

Comment: In the mentioned line you have two list-accesses. Try to separate them to isolate the source of error is a tip. But since in your if condition you already access `lst[i]` wihtout problems I guess the faulty index is  `my_lst[j]`

Answer (score 0):

The error is with the else part.

my_lst[j] does not exisit at that point(The len of my_lst is j -1)

So you'll have to append the first number to my_lst and not my_lst[j] (Similar to what you have done in the first line of the function)

```
my_lst.append([lst[i]])
```